# Beamer headline with frametitle

Tags: beamer, frame-title

Let's consider this MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4.8ex,dp=2ex,left]{section in head}
    \hspace{1ex}{\insertsection} -- {\insertframetitle}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{One}
  Hello
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Two}
  World
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Typesetting this, the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\beamer@@tmpl@headline ...} -- {\insertframetitle 
                                                  } \end {beamercolorbox} 
l.14 \begin{document}

?
```

occur. Is there a solution?

Comment: Insert \def\insertframetitle{} before \begin{document}

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Yes! It works.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Would you like to answer? Or close as "solved in comments"?

Comment: @samcarter - Solved in comments is fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments